# asp.net Oracle Tuning Thread Sleep

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have a web site in ASP.NET MVC 4.
This site persist data on Oracle's database. My Oracle.DataAcess.dll version is 4.112.3.0 (Runtime version: 4.0.30319). Below, the database information obtained executing the following command: 'select * from v$version';

[image: database info]

Well, I'm profiling my web site using Jet Brain's Dot Trace.
In my snapshot, they show me that two methods in 'Oracle.DataAcess.Client.OracleTuningAgent' are consuming more processor time. This methods are 'Oracle.DataAcess.Client.OracleTuningAgent.DoScan' and 'Oracle.DataAcess.Client.OracleTuningAgent.DoWait'. Either invoke the method 'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep'. Below, the snapshot information:

[image: Dot Trace snapshot]

I tryed add 'Self Tuning=false' in my connection string but they only stop to call DoWait function and continue to call 'DoScan' function.

There is a way to disable this functions to be called? Or is not a good idea do this?

Obs: Sorry for the bad english, actually I'm using google translator to help me to write this question.

Comment: I have the exact same issue... did you manage to find an answer? Thanks.

Comment: I found a solution in the following post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782169/oracle-data-provider-pegs-iis-worker-process-when-web-site-is-stopped
but did not solve the problem completely, some of these processes are still happening

Answer (score 0):

Phelps.

In my case, I grow up max pool size until there is no error.
as like this. "Max Pool Size=250;"

after all, I try to set it how many connections need for my application.
Also you need to tune up your connectionString
example )
Min/Max Pool Size
Incr/Decr Pool Size, too.

as below my comment.

Actually my problem caused by lack of oracle connections.
Because I didn't call "close()" after finish request.

If you have permission look up v$session table.
you can see growing up count of session. every your function running after.

but if you don't have a permission, you can use netstat -an .
with findstr /c:1521

Comment: Most of all, You must make sure close your Oracle connection "Close()"